# Nested relative layout animation not working

Tags: android, animation, android-relativelayout

I am trying to move an image in the vertical and horizontal direction and adding a shake effect to it too at the same time. I've nested the imageview in a relative layout which is nested in another relative layout. The top most relative layout is for translation in y-axis, the one coming under it is for translation in x-axis and the imageview has an infinite rotating animation on it. The problem is that i have translation in y axis and the shake animation on the imageview but the horizontal animation starts but doesn't work or repeat.

My layout structure is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ccolutions1.tiktokdownloader.SplashActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/splash_image_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp"
    android:paddingTop="50dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/splash_image_sway_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/splash_image"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/music_video_image" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My translation animation code :

```
RelativeLayout splashImageContainer = findViewById(R.id.splash_image_container);
    RelativeLayout splashImageSwayContainer = findViewById(R.id.splash_image_sway_container);
    ImageView splashImage = findViewById(R.id.splash_image);

    Animation shakeAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(SplashActivity.this, R.anim.rotate_animation);

    splashImage.startAnimation(shakeAnimation);

    TranslateAnimation bounceAnim = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -0.5f);
    bounceAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    bounceAnim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    bounceAnim.setDuration(1200);
    bounceAnim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    bounceAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
    bounceAnim.setFillAfter(true);

    TranslateAnimation swayAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f);
    bounceAnim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    bounceAnim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    bounceAnim.setDuration(600);
    bounceAnim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    bounceAnim.setFillEnabled(true);
    bounceAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    swayAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            System.out.println("swaying");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            System.out.println("swaying again");
        }
    });

    splashImageContainer.startAnimation(bounceAnim);
    splashImageSwayContainer.startAnimation(swayAnimation);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need just one `RelativeLayout`, not three, and use [Property Animators](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation) instead on `Animations`